# Restrict video access on vimeo until its paid for

Tags: e-commerce, vimeo, vimeo-api

Does anyone hvae any experience on Vimeo?  In particular, restricting access to videos which are held privately unless they've been paid for.

Scenario:
A user pays a small amount of money to access a video or selection of videos.

We are trying to avoid just showing the vimeo link and allowing access to be shared within the source because we revealed it once they paid.

Perhaps a token approach which expires after each session?  I'm not sure if this is possible?

Any thoughts or ideas on how we might approach this would be greatly appreciated.

We tried restricting it based on purchase but once paid, it allows a user to loop through vimeo id's to potentially get more than they paid for.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is go to `manage/videos/{video_id}/privacy`, set the video link to private, and set embed to a specific domain.

Anyone who for some reason gets the link to your Vimeo video won't be able to see the video anyway cuz it will display a 404 page on Vimeo. The embed URL also won't be of use to them because it will only work on your site (You have whitelisted your site's domain).

What I'd personally do is create a separate database for payments. When the user pays I will store a payment object that stores their username/userID and the Vimeo video ID or IDS. Maybe also an expiresIn prop to keep track of when it expires if it's subscription-based.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  We'll give it a go!